# Hide Textbox Field and Label associated with it

Tags: jquery, html

This is probably a pretty pointless question but I reckon it would be useful for many of us.

In this case's scenario, I would like to be able to hide a textbox and its label all in one go, without having to select both element and hiding them individually.

```
<label for="a">some text:</label>
<input type="text" class="text" id="a" />
```

So, for the above case, would it be possible to use a simple jQuery command to hide them both together?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could do this

```
$('label[for=a], input#a').hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/dYFMU/

`[ ]` selects the `attribute`.  In this case we are targeting a `for` attribute that equals `a`.

At the same time, we use a `,` to make another selection, the `input` with an `id=a`.

**EDIT**

Also, if you needed to do this for multiple `labels` and `inputs` you could put the `label` and `id` in an array as follows:

```
<label for="a">some text:</label>
<input type="text" class="text" id="a" />

<br />

<label for="b">some text:</label>
<input type="text" class="text" id="b" />

<br />

<label for="c">some text:</label>
<input type="text" class="text" id="c" />
```

js

```
var a = ['a','b','c'];

for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    $('label[for=' + a[i] + '], input#' + a[i]).hide();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/dYFMU/1/

Comment: Brilliant! That is short, easy to read and an excellent solution! Thanks a lot for this one!

Answer (score 2):

if you want to reuse the hiding, you can create a function similar to:

```
function hideTandem(id){
    $('#' + id + ', label[for=' + id + ']').hide();
}
```

and call it by supplying the id of the input

```
hideTandem('a');
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would probably be to just wrap them in a `div` and hide that instead.

```
<div id="hidethis">
  <label for="a">some text:</label>
  <input type="text" class="text" id="a" />
<div>

$("#hidethis).hide();
```

Comment: That would do it but isn't there anything else that could be used to hide them besides having to add a div element to the code, or rather, without having to add more html?

Comment: You could try chaining methods. Select the label, hide it, get `.next()` and then hide that one, but that wouldn't be a very good solution. That'd just be using jQuery for the sake of using jQuery. I would rather wrap them into a parent element or just make two separate calls. But I'm no jQuery expert, so if anyone else has a solution to this, I'd be interested to see it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Find the input however you want, and then you can find its ID using

```
var myInputBoxID = $(some selector).attr("id");
```

You can then reference the label by using the following syntax to catch the label's for attribute:

```
$("label[for=' + myInputBoxID + ']").hide();
```

You can probably nest things nicely so you don't need to store anything as a variable, and instead run through a "for each" on all the results of your input box selector. But anyway the key is finding the ID and then using that to find the label with label[for=...]